# How to trace outgoing interfaces?

Tags: ping, traceroute

The Unix command `traceroute` traces the IP addresses of the nodes from a source node to a destination node. Every node in between has an incoming and an outgoing interface.

[image: traceroute]

Executing `traceroute -n dst` on `src` will show the IP addresses of src, dst and all incoming interfaces of the hops in between.

But how to trace the outging IP addresses?

*Update*

I tried the `ping -R` suggestion but it does not seem to work. This is the traceroute to a public web server:

```
$ ping -n -c 1 -R 212.227.222.9
PING 212.227.222.9 (212.227.222.9) 56(124) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 212.227.222.9: icmp_req=1 ttl=57 time=47.4 ms
RR:     192.168.2.111
        169.254.1.1
        87.186.224.94
        62.154.76.34
        62.154.12.175
        212.227.117.13
        212.227.117.8
        10.71.3.253
        212.227.222.9


--- 212.227.222.9 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 47.441/47.441/47.441/0.000 ms
```

And this is the IP address of my dial-up connection.

```
$ curl -s https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/browserinfo/info/ | jq -r .remoteAddr
93.192.75.247
```

But it has not been recorded by the ping command. What can be the reason?

Comment: Tip: the quickest way to get your public IP is `curl ifconfig.me`. Simplest thing on the internet. Hands down.

Comment: ICMP will never give you the information you are looking to get accurately. The default behavior is to use the egress interface of the ICMP message, but it can generally be configured to be sourced from other interfaces.  Let's say I have an internet router that is using RFC1918 addressing between router interfaces within my own network, but I don't want to provide those addresses to the public, I can assign a public IP to a loopback interface and source all ICMP traffic from that interface.  You are getting neither the "incoming" nor the "outgoing" interfaces and never will from that device.

Comment: @RyanFoley ifconfig.me is not reliable (1 error in 5 tests) and it is slow: a query takes 2.8s. Google's toolbox needs 0.7s.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

I's not exactly the answer at your question, but that a simple (but limited) way to do (in certain case) what you want.
I'm coping-post the option -R of ping man page:

> -R     Record  route.   Includes the RECORD_ROUTE option in the ECHO_REQUEST packet and displays the **route buffer** on returned packets.
> Note that the IP header is only large enough for nine such routes.
> Many hosts ignore or discard this option.

So you can see also the **return path** of the ECHO_REQUEST, that is not the exit interface (that you are asking about) unless the outgoing path is the same of the come back path. Only in this case, the returning path is the IP address of the outgoing interface you are asking for.

*That's an real example on my internet provider net, maybe not so clear, but I don't have just now some router to link each other :)*
[image: dest 10.2.105.178]

```
traceroute 10.2.105.178
traceroute to 10.2.105.178 (10.2.105.178), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  3.418 ms  3.575 ms  4.021 ms
 2  10.189.48.1 (10.189.48.1)  11.237 ms * *
 3  10.2.105.178 (10.2.105.178)  15.235 ms * *
```

> ping -R 10.2.105.178 PING 10.2.105.178 (10.2.105.178) 56(124) bytes of
> data.
>
> 64 bytes from 10.2.105.178: icmp_req=5 ttl=253 time=74.1 ms NOP RR:
>
> 192.168.1.133
>
> 10.189.51.61
>
> 10.2.105.177
>
> 10.2.105.178
>
> 10.2.105.178
>
> 10.189.48.1
>
> 192.168.1.254
>
> 192.168.1.133
>
> ----omitted----
>
> 64 bytes from 10.2.105.178: icmp_req=6 ttl=253 time=13.0 ms NOP RR:
>
> 192.168.1.133
>
> 10.189.51.61
>
> 10.2.105.177
>
> 10.2.105.178
>
> 10.2.105.218 ##change every time, Idon't know why##
>
> 10.189.48.1
>
> 192.168.1.254
>
> 192.168.1.133

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly what RECORD_ROUTE does, but it does not seem to be, what I need. I tried it with a dial-up connection. I know the public address of my dial-up router and I have a route of nine hops to a public web server. For each of the hops I tried the `-R` option. The fourth hop was the first, who answered the request. But the answer does not contain my public address. And although it was only the fourth hop the answer contains 9 addresses.

Comment: just a moment, I'm preparing an exemple

Comment: The `ping -R` shall be useful only for very limited hop. I say before that is a restricted way

Comment: The same example does not work for my dial-up network. I have no idea why. Maybe NAT?

Comment: Hi @Ceving, do a `traceroute 212.227.222.9` and then do a `ping -R` **to the third hop** you found in the traceroute. In that way you have the same schema I did to read the response. The nine route **total** mean go and come back, so if you do `ping -R 212.227.222.9` you can't see the full path, but only the last part

Comment: the "remote address", I think, isn't the IP address of your access point, but a nat done by your internet provider. Or better, that what happen to me, that use fastweb. Really don't know the Deutsche Telekom policy. Cheers

Comment: Tx @YLearn  So, if I understood, the reason that the address _10.2.105.218 ##change every time, Idon't know why##_ flapping every icmp_req shall be originate by a sort of "random loopback interface". Correct?

Answer (score 6):

According to [RFC1812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812) the source address of ICMP message generated by the router should be that of the egress interface over which the packet would normally return to the sender.

In reality, it is very likely that you will face non-standard behavior where router will source the ICMP reply with the source of ingress interface. This usually make the traceroute much easier to read.

As a follow-up to YLearn's question I'm posting a network diagram and some outputs.
[image: Sample topology to illustrate how traceroute works]

Let's assume we are souring the traceroute from R5's loopback 5.5.5.5 to R1's loopback 1.1.1.1. As you can see, the forward path is via R4-R2, while reverse path is R3-R4.

```
R4#sh ip route 1.1.1.1
Routing entry for 1.1.1.1/32
Known via "bgp 4", distance 20, metric 0
Tag 2, type external
Last update from 10.1.24.2 00:02:42 ago
Routing Descriptor Blocks:
* 10.1.24.2, from 10.1.24.2, 00:02:42 ago
  Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
  AS Hops 2

R1#sh ip route 5.5.5.5
Routing entry for 5.5.5.5/32
Known via "bgp 1", distance 20, metric 0
Tag 3, type external
Last update from 10.1.13.3 00:14:18 ago
Routing Descriptor Blocks:
* 10.1.13.3, from 10.1.13.3, 00:14:18 ago
  Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
  AS Hops 2
  Route tag 3
  MPLS label: none
```

The traceroute output from R5 looks as following:

```
R5#traceroute
Protocol [ip]:
Target IP address: 1.1.1.1
Source address: 5.5.5.5
Numeric display [n]:
Timeout in seconds [3]:
Probe count [3]:
Minimum Time to Live [1]:
Maximum Time to Live [30]:
Port Number [33434]:
Loose, Strict, Record, Timestamp, Verbose[none]:
Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 1.1.1.1
VRF info: (vrf in name/id, vrf out name/id)
1 10.1.45.4 208 msec 140 msec 100 msec
2 10.1.24.2 96 msec 44 msec 104 msec
3 10.1.12.1 224 msec 220 msec 112 msec
```

So while the actual ICMP traffic generated by R1 is going back to R5 via R3, the IP header of ICMP Unreachable message will have the source of ingress interface 10.1.12.1.

In my experience this how Cisco and Juniper routers behave, I'm not sure about other vendors.

Comment: Probably just me, but the second sentence has me a bit confused.  Are you saying it is common for a device on the internet to respond using the ingress interface of the traffic that caused the generation of the ICMP message?  So if the traffic is received on Int1, and the ICMP message goes out Int2, it is sourced from Int1? Or are you referring to a different ingress interface (and if so, which)? In my experience, most routers work as the RFC states, using the egress interface of the message by default, and that in most cases this is the same interface the traffic was received on.